# Bootstrap - Text wrap around the image block

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use `float:` of css or bootstrap `pull-left`, and the image is on the left and text on the right wrap the text.

However, the problem is my image block has 2 buttons, the layout is fine, but buttons are unclickable. Because the text area is still wide and over the image block.
Any way to solve this problem?Thanks guys.

[image]

Comment: Please post relevant code so people can better help. Hard to see what's happening here.

Comment: Try using z-index:100; on the container that holds the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the text area which is on top, where the text is, you can add property `pointer-events:none`

Comment: You are awesome pkg. All work good. You saved my time. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :)